# Datepicker is not working when I use APPEND function in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

HTML Code

```
<tbody class="rowdetail">
<tr style="width:100%;">
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:150px;" class="form-control odate" name="opening_date[]" id="opening_date1" value="<?php echo $opening_date1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="time" style="width:" class="form-control" name="garage_out_time[]" id="garage_out_time1" value="<?php echo $garage_out_time1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" name="garage_out_km[]" id="garage_out_km1" value="<?php echo $garage_out_km1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="time" style="width:" class="form-control" name="reporting_time[]" id="reporting_time1" value="<?php echo $reporting_time1[$j] ?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" name="reporting_km[]" id="reporting_km1" value="<?php echo $reporting_km1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:150px" class="form-control cdate" name="closing_date[]" id="closing_date1" value="<?php echo $closing_date1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="time" style="width:" class="form-control" name="closing_time[]" id="closing_time1" value="<?php echo $closing_time1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" name="closing_km[]" id="closing_km1" value="<?php echo $closing_km1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="time" style="width:" class="form-control" name="garage_in_time[]" id="garage_in_time1" value="<?php echo $garage_in_time1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" name="garage_in_km[]" id="garage_in_km1" value="<?php echo $garage_in_km1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="time" style="width:" class="form-control" name="total_hours[]" id="total_hours1" value="<?php echo $total_hours1[$j]?>" required></td>
                                <td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" name="total_km[]" id="total_km1" value="<?php echo $total_km1[$j]?>" required></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php }?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="AddRow();">Add</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="RemoveRow();">Remove</button><br><br>                    
                    </div>
```

I am trying to use `from to date` `datepicker` here. When page is loaded  `datepicker` is coming. But when I `append` , `datepicker` is not coming. Below is my code.

```
var i=1;
function AddRow(){
if($(".rowdetail tr").length<7)
        {
            $(".rowdetail").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control odate1" id="opening_date2" name="opening_date[]"></td><td><input type="time" class="form-control" id="garage_out_time2" name="garage_out_time[]"></td><td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" id="garage_out_km2" name="garage_out_km[]"></td><td><input type="time" class="form-control" id="reporting_time2" name="reporting_time[]"></td><td><input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" id="reporting_km2" name="reporting_km[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control cdate1" id="closing_date2" name="closing_date[]"></td><td><input type="time" class="form-control" id="closing_time2" name="closing_time[]"></td><td><input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" id="closing_km2" name="closing_km[]"></td><td><input type="time" class="form-control" id="garage_in_time2" name="garage_in_time[]"></td><td><input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" id="garage_in_km2" name="garage_in_km[]"></td><td><input type="time" class="form-control" id="total_hours2" name="total_hours[]"></td><td><input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" id="total_km2" name="total_km[]"></td></tr>');
            i = i+1;                
        }           
        else
        {
            alert("You cannot add more rows");
        }  
}
function RemoveRow(){
if($(".rowdetail tr").length>1)
        {
            $(".rowdetail tr:last-child").remove();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You cannot delete first row");
        }
}
```

Here is my `from to date` `datepicker` code

```
$(function () {
$(".odate1").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        $(".cdate1").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
});
$(".cdate1").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $(".odate1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
});
});
```

How to display `from to date` `datepicker` when the `textbox` is dynamically created?

JsFiddle Below

https://jsfiddle.net/u90evvrn/

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: @Pk19000 I Updated the html code. Please look at it.

Comment: Most of these scripts apply to DOM elements. Since you "create" something that does not exist on page load, it's impossible for the datepicker to be applied on the new field. You must execute again the datepicker on your AddRow() function, right after you append the new field

Comment: @andrew I applied the above `datepicker` code inside `AddRow()` function . For the first append` textbox` it was showing `detepicker` BUT when I add/append another  `textbox` the third `textbox` will also show `datepicker` and I selected `datepicker` value BUT  when I select `date` in the third `textbox` after once again I `append` , second `textbox` value  is editing not the third/selected `textbox` `date` value.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ create a fiddle so that people will help you

Comment: @Kirataka hm... it seems it gets applied in all classes. Perhaps you should try it with something unique (like ids or unique classes)

Comment: @andrew But when I append I cant assign unique `ID's` to each one. That's why I tried `Class` . But still is not working.

Comment: And here is jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/u90evvrn/

Comment: @Kirataka sure you can. You already count rows (`if($(".rowdetail tr").length<7)`). So you already know that you are, for example in row 3. Assign a unique class, something like 'odateX', and your jquery selector can be `$(".odate"+i)`, where i is the row you are/append. Same strategy with ids `$("#picker"+i)`